# How can I manipulate cartesian coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have a collection of basic cartesian coordinates and I'd like to manipulate them with Python.  For example, I have the following box (with coordinates show as the corners):

0,4---4,4

0,0---4,0

I'd like to be able to find a row that starts with (0,2) and goes to (4,2).  Do I need to break up each coordinate into separate X and Y values and then use basic math, or is there a way to process coordinates as an (x,y) pair?  For example, I'd like to say:

```
New_Row_Start_Coordinate = (0,2) + (0,0)
New_Row_End_Coordinate = New_Row_Start_Coordinate + (0,4)
```

Comment: *"I'd like to be able to find a row"* - sorry, I don't get it. What does it mean, to find a row? You already know the coordinates, don't you?

Comment: I simply meant to identify a row for further processing.  For example, I may want to find a point on the nth row up from the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a Point class. Here's a simple one:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y

  def __str__(self):
    return "{}, {}".format(self.x, self.y)

  def __neg__(self):
    return Point(-self.x, -self.y)

  def __add__(self, point):
    return Point(self.x+point.x, self.y+point.y)

  def __sub__(self, point):
    return self + -point
```

You can then do things like this:

```
>>> p1 = Point(1,1)
>>> p2 = Point(3,4)
>>> print p1 + p2
4, 5
```

You can add as many other operations as you need. For a list of all of the methods you can implement, see the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Answer (score 1):

depending on what you want to do with the coordinates, you can also misuse the [complex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cmath.html) numbers:

```
import cmath

New_Row_Start_Coordinate = (0+2j) + (0+0j)
New_Row_End_Coordinate = New_Row_Start_Coordinate + (4+0j)

print New_Row_End_Coordinate.real
print New_Row_End_Coordinate.imag
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't natively support elementwise operations on lists; you could do it via list comprehensions or `map` but that's a little clunky for this use case. If you're doing a lot of this kind of thing, I'd suggest looking at [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For `a = (0,2)` and `b = (0,0)` `a + b` will yield `(0, 2, 0, 0)`, which is probably not what you want. I suggest to use `numpy`'s `add` function: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html

> Parameters :  x1, x2 : array_like
>
> Returns: The sum of x1 and x2, element-wise. (...)